# A Question Regarding the Construction of Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I was watching a video while learning the intuition behind the Fourier transform, the link to the video is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY&t=150s

My question is, at 4:47. Why does the Fourier graph attain a 'peak' when the winding frequency matches the frequency of the signal?

How do we formalize this question mathematically? Is this statement a result of some theorem(s), what are their names?

Comment: The Fourier transform can be viewed as converting from the time domain to the frequency domain. For example assuming one defines the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ as $\mathcal{F}_t[f(t)](\omega)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\, e^{i 2 \pi \omega t} \, dt$, then the Fourier transform of $\cos(2 \pi f t)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t[\cos(2 \pi f t)](\omega)=\frac{\delta(\omega+f)}{2}+\frac{\delta(\omega-f)}{2}$ where the two Dirac delta functions represent impulses at $\omega=-f$ and $\omega=f$.